# Running a macro from a non-activeX button

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Is it possible to run a macro in Powerpoint from a non-ActiveX button? For instance just a circle shape I place on the slide? I haven't found a way to connect a macro to anything but an ActiveX button. However there are some smart people here that may know a work around.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. First, make sure the subroutine containing the code is declared as Public.

Then add an Action Setting to your circle/other shape.  Set the action setting to Run Macro: [choose the macro to run]

Note: you can also do this, which is sometimes quite useful:

Public Sub MyMacro (oSh as Shape)
   Msgbox "You clicked a shape called " & oSh.Name _
   & VbCRLF _
   & "on slide " & Cstr(oSh.Parent.SlideIndex)
End Sub

By getting a reference to the shape, you can find out what slide it's on or, depending on the shape type or name or any of a number of other attributes, perform different actions.

This is broken on Mac PPT.  There's a way around it described on my PPT FAQ site, here:

Determine which shape was clicked
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00141_Determine_which_shape_was_clicked.htm